# show message success when confirm a form by ajax & jquery

Tags: php, forms, message, show

when user write her email for Newsletters, i want to show them a suuccess       message

```
newsletter.php
<?php
$templates="templates/";
require_once 'includes/init.inc.php';
//require_once 'includes/classes/email.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (($result=mail::add_newsletter($_REQUEST['email'])) >0) {
            Util::Redirect("index.php");
  } else {
      echo 'you register befor';
}
    }
?>
footer.php
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post" class="searchform" >
                                <input  type="text" placeholder=" type your email" name="email" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
                                <p >come on with us to know everything for us</p>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use session to store success message, and you can print it after redirect.

Comment: session?i think i have to do it by jquery